# Angular directive not being re-called with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive `ct-steps-tooltip` on an element along with `ng-repeat` like so:

```
<div id='courseSteps' 
     class='relative ease {{step.action.toLowerCase()}}' 

     ng-repeat='step in currentItem.userData.steps | filter:{action: filterSteps} track by $index' 
     ng-class='{"completed": step.endDate, "pointer": step.action==="Submit" && !step.endDate}' 
     ng-click='getRelated(step, $index)'

     ct-steps-tooltip 
     ct-step-name="step.stepName" 
     ct-step-description="step.description" 
     ct-action="step.action" 
     ct-value-text="step.valueText" 
     ct-quantity='steps.length' 
     ct-completed='currentItem.steps.completedSteps' 
     ct-start-date='step.startDate' 
     ct-end-date='step.endDate'>

    <div ng-show='step.endDate' class="stepCompleteCheck absolute"></div>
    <div> {{ step.stepName }} </div>
</div>
```

My goal was to get the directive to re-bind/get called again whenever `currentItem.userData.steps` changed (I am actually completely clearing `currentItem` and then reassigning it). This actually works great in [this simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z52h/) I made. In the fiddle you can clearly see "I got called!" in the console every time the data is changed. For some reason, the `ct-steps-tooltip` directive in the real code only gets called the first time, and doesn't get called again when the data changes (I have a similar "I got called" message in the real directive's `link` function). What am I doing in the real code that has broken this functionality?

**EDIT:** Noticing that OCCASIONALLY the directive IS called again on data change. Its happening like 10% of the time. My question is now seeming similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718027/angular-directive-in-ng-repeat-doesnt-call-link?rq=1).

Comment: So, can we see some of that *"real"* code you're talking about? How do you change the data in it?

Comment: The whole thing is too massive to reasonably post here. To change the data I am calling a function on a button click which does:`$scope.currentItem = newItem;` pretty much how I do it in the fiddle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data is not refreshing because in your `ngRepeat` expression, you specify `track by $index`.

When `currentItem` is updated, the *indices* of objects in your `steps` array remain the same even if the actual *objects* are different.

Therefore angular does not update the repeater because the `$index` has not changed and we are tracking the step objects by this `$index` variable. Remove the `track by` part of the repeater expression and your problem will be solved.

`track by` is really only useful when you are adding and removing objects to/from an array in the repeater, not when you are changing the entire array. For example, if you have a list of 100 books and you add one to this array (without `track by`), the entire array of 101 books would be re-rendered. You could use `track by book.id` to tell angular that the original 100 books in the repeater have not changed and to only render dom for the single book we are adding.

Comment: +1 this is correct. With the `track by $index` clause, it's not going to destroy/recreate DOM elements unless the size of the watched array changes. That means that it won't re-`$compile` the ng-repeat's transcluded content for anything that is within an array of the same size.  You *should* probably still use `track by` because of the efficiencies you gain in doing so, but you might want to track the object by something else, an id, or a hash perhaps.

Comment: Awesome. Knew this would be related to some little angular nugget I hadn't gleaned yet. I'm my case I'm only dealing with an array that shouldn't ever be more than 15 items or so, so `track by` is out!

Comment: I actually found another solution to this too. I basically ajax in a template with some angular mark up in it, and `$compile` it with the directives link `scope`. This seems to work even with `track by $index`. Why is that? Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UX5N4/1/